# Angular JS Directive Unloading Event or Equivalent

Tags: javascript, angularjs

So, I have these widgets:

```
<widget ng-repeat="widget in widgets"></widget>
```

As you can tell, they are created and removed by the `ng-repeat`.

So when someone does remove a widget, is there any where in the directive I can catch the event happening OR equivalent?

```
.directive('widget', function widget() {
    var directive = { 
        restrict: 'E',
        compile: compile
    };

    return directive;

    function compile() {
        return {
            pre: preLink,
            post: postLink
        };
    }

    function preLink(scope, element) {

    }

    function postLink(scope, element) {

    }
});
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can listen to the [$destroy](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$destroy) event which will be fired immediately prior to scope destruction.

> The $destroy() is usually used by directives such as ngRepeat for managing the unrolling of the loop.

```
scope.$on('$destroy', function () {
    console.log('captured $destroy event');
});
```

Comment: Sweet, will be trying that out!!